# How to give full access to a folder for everyone?

Tags: windows

How to give full access to a folder for everyone?

Is there any way to do it programmatically, using a .bat file or a script?

Comment: What OS?  I assume Windows given the .bat, but what version?

Comment: on windows-7 and windows-server-2008

Comment: Where is the folder; on the server or on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool called iCacls from microsoft.

[This](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/59575-icacls-windows-7-modify-permissons-everyone-user-file-folder.html) page illustrates the exact thing that you need.

Since it supports command line operation, you can easily write a batch with it.

PS:
The guy is initially saying that it isn't working on win 7.
BUT, go down the comments and he got it to work.